# How to connect Postgres sql to GCP for a Flask application

Tags: postgresql, flask, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect GCP's postgresql database to a flask application, I have been following the GCP guide:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql-postgres

But the issue comes up is when I try to run the server locally, it keeps saying:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/cloudsql/omedyari:us-west2:kong/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Which I am compelteely confused, I have tried searching the internet went through a lot of the GCP documentation, but I really have no idea as to why this is not working.

This is how, I am setting up the URI:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql+psycopg2://[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]@/postgres?host=/cloudsql/[CONNECTION_NAME]/[DB_NAME]'
```

Comment: Have you installed and started the cloud_sql_proxy on your local machine as explained in the doc you linked?

Comment: How was this issue resolved? Please reply to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66942285/connecting-to-google-cloud-sql-postgres-instance-using-psycopg2