# Connecting to Google Cloud SQL Postgres instance using psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, flask, psycopg2, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to Google Cloud SQL Postgres Using psycopg2.

I have created an postgreSQL instance and using the default database `postgres` for now.
I am able to connect from pgadmin tool as well as from the gcloud shell and the queries give expected result.

I have developed a flask application and deploying on standard app engine.

`conn = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres", user = "postgres", password = "password", host = "/cloudsql/my-new-db")`

And when I run it, the get `psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory` error.

I have a hunch that host value is not correct. I tried various options like `/cloudsql/<prj-name>.<region>.<db-instance-name>`

But, nothing seems to be working. What else should I be doing to remove this error?

Comment: Hello! I'm building something similar. Do you happen to have a full solution to what you've done? I am running into some issues that I couldn't resolve with the below solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#public-ip-default) on connecting to Cloud SQL from app engine:

Connecting with Unix sockets

Once correctly configured, you can connect your service to your Cloud SQL instance's Unix domain socket accessed on the environment's filesystem at the following path: /cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME.

The INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME can be found on the Overview page for your instance in the Google Cloud Console or by running the following command:

```
    gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]
```

edit: formatting

Comment: I am using psycopg2 module and not the sqlalchemy ORM. Can you help me with the psycopg2 module?

Comment: UNIX socket path is same whether you yse sqlalchemy or psycopg2.

Comment: posted my solution as an answer

Answer (score 2):

```
unix_socket = '/cloudsql/{}'.format("my-project-id:us-central1:my-db-name")

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres", user = "postgres", password = "password", host = unix_socket)
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

on your flask server make sure to install the psycopg2 library (pip install or use apt-get install). I have attached a small snippet of code that I have for successful connection to my Postgres database and maybe it will assist in some way. I noticed you don't have a port specified.

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(
   user = 'userName',
   password = password,
   host = 'some ip here',
   port = '5432',
   database = 'db name here'
)
```

The host in my case is the IP of the server which has a port forwarded for access to my flask server. I am not sure what way you are accessing your host. My flask API and DB are actually hosted on separate VM's within google cloud. I hope this helped at all, if it doesn't maybe more context could be provided and I could look at it more.